# Exe-файл в java

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени суток!

Я наконец дописал програму на java, теперь встает вопрос, как сделать exe-файл? И можно ли запускать ее с телефона (можно ли это сделать вообще, если он поддерживает только jar или jad)?

Подскажите, кто знает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте *.bat файл для запуска вашего java-приложения под windows. Эта статья вам поможет
http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/dos-batch-files-compile-run-java-program-create-jar-file

На этот батник можно навесить ярлык, и ярлык разместить уже где угодно - на рабочем столе, в меню кнопке пуск и т.д.

С телефоном все сложнее. Если писали под симбиан нокию, то для этого придется портировать вашу программу java под Java ME. Android портировать под андроид и его Android SDK. Если все было написано хорошо - особых проблем вызвать не должно, т.к. основые проблемы и расхождения в юзер интерфейсе (Swing и AWT скорее всего не прокатят).

Ява программа чаще всего - это запускаемый jar файл. Который запускается уже где угодно. Но у каждой платформы есть свои собственные ограничения

Answer (score 1):

А зачем делать exe? На то она и java. С другой стороны, сделаете Вы exe, и что потом с ним делать? под Linux уже не запустится так просто.
Запускать с телефона можно, но нужно компилировать с правильным SDK для конкретного телефона/модели.

Comment: А как можно запустить мою програмку что бы не запускать среду java?

Comment: никак. На то она и java.

Comment: Никак. Джава работает только с JVM. В линуксе был проект gcj - компилятор, переводящий программы на джаве в обычные исполняемые файлы, но он уже несколько лет заброшен. Применение JVM обеспечивает основу философии Java - кроссплатформенность.

Comment: На ПК я запускаю jar а на телефоне samsung wave 525 пишет недопустимый файл

Comment: логично, кто бы сомневался.

Answer (score 0):

Для **desktop**-приложений существуют специальный программные средства, которые позволяют сделать.

Примеры:

- Eclipse RCP
- NativeJ