# Java как сделать файл запускаемым

Tags: java

У меня есть код на Java, я могу превратить его в exe но как я понял это плохо. Как сделать так чтобы я мог запускать его без команды, как обычное приложение. На любой системе.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/59618/exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-java?rq=1

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Exe-файл в java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/59618/exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Можно ли как сделать, чтобы jar файл запускался на компьютерах без установленного JRE? Может быть как-то внедрить внутрь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/911049/204271)